# mailer spec test fails, but should pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, rspec-rails

In a rails 4 app I have a mailer called admin_mailer that sends an email when a order is created.

Here is the mailer:

```
  def order_notification(order)
    @order = order
    mail(
          :to => ENV['ADMIN_EMAIL'],
          :subject => "New order #{order.id}",
          :from => ENV['EMAIL_PROVIDER_USERNAME']
          )
  end
```

Here is the relevant view:

```
h1
  New order!
%p
  Thank you
  = @order.user.name
  A new order has been created.
```

The mail is sent correctly, but still the following test fails:

```
scenario 'order_notification should show user name' do
    user = create(:user, name: 'Alan Ford')
    mycart = create(:cart)
    vest = create(:product, name: 'vest', price: '250000')
    jacket = create(:product, name: 'jacket-1', price: '300000')
    line_vest = create(:line_item, product: vest, unit_price: vest.price, cart: mycart)
    line_jacket = create(:line_item, product: jacket, unit_price: jacket.price, cart: mycart)
    order = create(:order, cart: mycart, user: user, amount: '550000')
    AdminMailer.order_notification(order).deliver_now
    puts ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first.body
    expect(ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.first.body).to include 'Alan Ford'
  end
```

I added the puts line in the test so I can see on screen the actual result of the test, which is fine:

```
<h1>
New order!
</h1>
<p>
Thank you
Alan Ford
A new order has been created.
</p>
```

Still the test is failing:

```
  1) AdminMailer order_notification should send an email
     Failure/Error: AdminMailer.order_notification(order).deliver_now
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/admin_mailer/order_notification.html.haml:5:in `_app_views_admin_mailer_order_notification_html_haml___3279210695024268720_62832180'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionview-4.2.0/lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
[... a lot more lines ...]
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `new'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:25:in `__getobj__'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:34:in `message'
     # /home/andrea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3/gems/actionmailer-4.2.0/lib/action_mailer/message_delivery.rb:85:in `deliver_now'
     # ./spec/mailers/admin_mailer_spec.rb:61:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

@order.user cannot be nil, since the @order.user.name is displayed correctly in the email, and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Comment: the failing test is not the one you've posted  (it's the "order_notification should send an email" that is failing)

Comment: Of course... I've been trying to fix that for hours and I forgot to look into the obvious. Thank you